# How to present a list in chunks using php?

Tags: php, foreach

I wish to display a (flat) list of records in chunks of 3 items like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2></div>
  <div id="item3"><div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="item4"></div>
  <div id="item5></div>
  <div id="item6"><div>
</div>
```

Those item1 to n will be retrieved from a db query.

The problem are the wrapper divs.
It seems I need to slit a `foreach` in n chucks?

Can I have a little push here?

Comment: push... One loop and `%` modulus operator.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks. ;) I will have a look.

Comment: I found this question very unclear, not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JackWilliams In order to clarify, I need to understand what is not clear to you.

Comment: I just don't get what your goal is here, you haven't provided much background, maybe it's just me - which is why I didn't down-vote.

Comment: @JackWilliams The goal is to build that html structure using php. Those item1 to item n, belong to a database query data that should be retrieved and placed inside those placeholders.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and in that case i think @Arian has got the solution I'd go for.

Comment: I'm using a `foreach` already and it's quite handy. Also, having echo's all around, specially, when you have a lot of html attributes inside your html tags, isn't that easy to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$end = 20;

for($count = 1; $count <= $end; $count++){

    if(($count % 3) == 1)
        echo '<div class="wrapper">';

    echo '<div id="item'.$count.'"></div>';

    if(($count % 3) == 0 || $count == $end)
        echo '</div>';
}
```

EDIT (separated the HTML from PHP per request in comments):

```
$end = 20;

for($count = 1; $count <= $end; $count++){

    if(($count % 3) == 1){
        ?>
            <div class="wrapper">
        <?php
    }

    ?>

    <div id="item<?=$count?>"></div>

    <?php
    if(($count % 3) == 0 || $count == $end){
        ?>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your code organisation. But I'm using a foreach, and those div while simple on this example, are quite complex on the real thing, so it would be better to clearly separate php from html... Do you thing, your code could be re-arranged to fit those requirements?

Comment: I would like to test and play with php quickly to try those and other possibilities. I'm using a heavy framework structure, making kind of hard to test those little things. How do you do it? Thanks.

Comment: @MEM I updated my code, to separate the PHP from HTML... look at my updated answer.

Comment: I will properly study it. Thanks a lot. The answer has been accepted.

Comment: @MEM you can use http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com to test small php code snippets

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function renderWrapperStart($i) {
    if ($i % 3 !== 0) {
        return;
    }
?>
    <div class="wrapper">
<?
}

function renderWrapperEnd($i) {
    if ($i % 3 !== 0 || $i == 0) {
        return;
    }
?>
    </div>
<?
}

function renderItem($i, $id, $content) {
?>
    <div id="<?= $id ?>"><?= $content ?></div>
<?
}

$items = array(
    'item1' => 'content 1',
    'item2' => 'content 2',
    'item3' => 'content 3',
    'item4' => 'content 4',
    'item5' => 'content 5',
    'item6' => 'content 6'
);

$i = 0;

foreach ($items as $id => $content) {
    renderWrapperEnd($i);
    renderWrapperStart($i);
    renderItem($i, $id, $content);
    $i++;
}

renderWrapperEnd($i);
?>
```

Output is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="item1">content 1</div>
        <div id="item2">content 2</div>
        <div id="item3">content 3</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="item4">content 4</div>
        <div id="item5">content 5</div>
        <div id="item6">content 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your approach, but if I echo the divs with 10 attributes, and N classes declared on those tags, I will end up with a lot of `\n\t` on a huge string, making it very hard to debug... I would prefer to clearly split html from php.

Comment: I've updated with an example that uses HTML directly instead of using `echo` statements.

Comment: I accepted Arian, because it was the first answer I sought. Thanks for your alternative, it will allow me to learn as well.

Answer (score -1):

is this what you want ?

```
for($i=1 ; $i<= n ; $i++){
  if($i%3 == 0) {
      echo '<div class="wrapper">';
  }
  echo '<div id="item'.$i.'"></div>';
  if($i%3 == 0) {
     echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree! Don't conditionally echo the `<div>` or `</div>`

Comment: do you have any other way ?

Comment: Your variables aren't even `$`, and your logic is completely incorrect.

Comment: that's just typo. it's not important than logic. why downvote?

Comment: @TechnoKnol because if you actually tested this code, you would notice that it doesn't output anything near the right answer: `<div id="item1"></div><div id="item2"></div><div class="wrapper"><div id="item3"></div></div>`

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean ?

```
array_chunk($arr, 3);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: I've seen array_chuck with the `true` argument, that allow us to preserve the `index`, but... how can I use this to echo what I want? Do I really need to split the array into chucks?